# Collecting standard onepage checkout improvements for extension

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

there are many discussions of onestepcheckout over onepagecheckout. Possible advantages of 
onestepcheckout are known. We however decided to stick to default Magento - but! with some conversion improving aditions. For example based on this article: http://ampersandcommerce.com/6-ways-to-improve-conversion-for-magento-enterprise-one-page-checkout/

**Now my question is:** what are simple improvements we can make (and should make) to the default onepagecheckout of Magento to increase conversion?

**For example**

1. Remove header and footer in checkout (20% conversion increase)
   http://convertify.co.uk/improving-the-conversion-rate-of-the-magento-default-checkout/
2. Replace guest checkout with button - Enter e-mail and Click to
   continue
   [image: Capture email at step 1 + continue]
3. (and/or) move E-mail entry field up in address form (and save by ajax onchange) to capture for cart abandonment follow-up
4. Add social login buttons for quick email and address entry above address form
5. Add a text link asking for couponcode (but not in your face so customers starts a oole search for coupon code)
6. Maybe skip he cart (if and when +, -, delete & small image are present in review step)
7. Show all forms/steps on same page (scroll to next item, no reloading)
8. Social like and fast create account on success page
9. Option to add custom CMS blocks underneath every step (if block exist then show)
10. Auto select common options (guest + same as shippin address)
    http://icebergcommerce.com/software/blog/iss/article/easy-magento-checkout-page-improvements
11. Add a trust logo to the checkout (if you have one)
    http://convertify.co.uk/improving-the-conversion-rate-of-the-magento-default-checkout/
    also as seen on samcart
12. What do you think?

**And a side question:** Do any extensions exist that do some of this above?